# How to deserialize a more complex Json Doc in Vb.net with Newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have a rest API which returns me a json response which is an array of docs which in turn has multiple arrays it self. Below is a sample of a doc i like to deserialize

```
{
             "DocId": "contact::6f128681-218d-409d-b71d-31031852057d",
             "Name": "Joe F Miller",
             "buckets": [
                {
                     "DocId": "leadbucket::5652A756-5B58-45A5-9566-9C85E8783440",
                     "text": "Dead Leads"
                },
                {
                     "DocId": "leadbucket::8A234FC1-6389-485D-8BDE-7FCB1E7639E0",
                     "text": "No Follow-Up Needed"
                },
                {
                     "DocId": "leadbucket::C97632BE-5A24-4AE7-8D18-4DFE174F0D0F",
                     "text": "Long-Term Buyers"
                },
                {
                     "DocId": "leadbucket::D6802064-8AC5-4E5A-855E-B59C32859C81",
                     "text": "New Lead"
                }
            ],
             "emails": [
                {
                     "other": "demo@test.com"
                },
                {
                     "work": "work@demo.com"
                },
                {
                     "work": "work2@demo.com"
                }
            ],
             "followup": {
                 "date": "05/01/2019",
                 "type": "phone"
            },
             "lastactivity": "04/05/2019",
             "phones": [
                {
                     "home": "(213) 444-2222"
                },
                {
                     "work": "(949) 555-1212"
                }
            ],
             "tags": [
                {
                     "DocId": "tag::FC276FBD-DC3A-4E18-8244-E89EF24E022E",
                     "text": "Buyer"
                },
                {
                     "DocId": "tag::EA5DE0FB-34B0-4F7C-B631-177D6BD2F65E",
                     "text": "Investor"
                }
            ]
        }
```

After i get the response from my API i use the below code to try to convert the data.

```
ContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Contact.ContactList))(read.Item("Data").ToString)
```

So i hope someone can point me in the right direction on how to create a class to store this type of doc and how to Deserialize it. Do i have to do this in my class or do i have to call a Deserialize for each array in the Json ?

Another issue i have is the emails and phones section, as the key value is not unique and i dont always know what will get returned. how would i build a class to store this as the key field can change.

Comment: Try http://json2csharp.com, it will generate the correct class structure to deserialise the JSON into

Comment: How and where would i implement the IEnumerable(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) ? i would assume i would put it in the Class which defines the data for this. I was able to figure out the buckets and tags which i created in my class as List( of tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example, using an `IEnumerable(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))` to deserialize JSON Objects that have an undefined number of elements, with an undefined combination of (Key, Value) pairs per object.
The Key part may also repeat, as shown in the exmple:

```
 "emails": [
    {"other": "demo@test.com"},
    {"work": "work@demo.com"},
    {"work": "work2@demo.com"}
```

The **`other`**, **`work`** keys may be different each time and may repeat.

Deserializing/Serializing this property with a `IEnumerable(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))`, allows to

The sample class object, Contacts, contains the methods (simplified, here) that perform the deserialization of the JSON Object and the seriaization of the Object Root, reproducing the original JSON Object.

These methods are static (Shared), you just need to call the method, no need to create an instance of the Contacts class.
For example, deserialize a JSON Object (a string received from a service):

```
Dim myContacts As Contacts.RootObject = Contacts.DeserializeJSON(JSONObject)
```

Serialize the class object back to the original string:

```
Dim myJsonContacts = Contacts.SerializeJSON(myContacts)
```

Compare the JSON just serialized to the original and to see whether they match.

List all the Emails and Phone Numbers in the deserialized class object:
(just an example: converting to List is not necessary)

```
myContacts.Emails.ToList().ForEach(
    Sub(em) Console.WriteLine($"from: {em.Keys(0)}, Email: {em.Values(0)}"))

myContacts.Phones.ToList().ForEach(
    Sub(ph) Console.WriteLine($"place: {ph.Keys(0)}, Phone Number: {ph.Values(0)}"))
```

Access a single Email (or Phone Number):
(any other method to extract the `(Key, Value)` pair from a Dictionary can of course be used)

```
Dim eMailFrom = myContacts.Emails(0).Keys(0)
Dim eMailValue = myContacts.Emails(0).Values(0)
```

Get all the Emails from a specific location (`work`, here):

```
Dim emailFromWork = myContacts.Emails.Where(Function(em) em.Keys.Contains("work"))
```

---

The **`Contacts`** class:
Some properties are decorated with a `<JsonProperty()>`. The property name is changed because the original JSON uses names that are reserved keywords in the language.

For example:

`<JsonProperty("text")>`
`Public Property BucketText As String`

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Contacts

    Public Shared Function DeserializeJSON(JsonObject As String) As RootObject
        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(JsonObject)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SerializeJSON(classObject As RootObject) As String
        Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classObject)
    End Function

    Partial Public Class RootObject
        Public Property DocId As String
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Buckets As List(Of Bucket)
        Public Property Emails As Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        Public Property Followup As Followup
        Public Property Lastactivity As String
        Public Property Phones As IEnumerable(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Public Property Tags As List(Of Tag)
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Bucket
        Public Property DocId As String
        <JsonProperty("text")>
        Public Property BucketText As String
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Tag
        Public Property DocId As String
        <JsonProperty("text")>
        Public Property TagText As String
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Followup
        <JsonProperty("date")>
        Public Property FollowupDate As String

        <JsonProperty("type")>
        Public Property FollowupType As String
    End Class
End Class
```